# Error: operator "defined" requires an identifier

Tags: c, macos, c-preprocessor, preprocessor-directive

I have been searching for an hour about this seemingly obvious question, and read several other posts including [this one with the same title](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23468369/5358284), but I am still struggling to find a convincing answer. Please forgive my ignorance in advance, and consider this code:

```
#define MY_MACRO 1
#define IMPLEMENT(x) (defined(x) && (x))

#if IMPLEMENT(MY_MACRO)
#define TESTVAL 1
#else
#define TESTVAL 0
#endif

#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    printf("Value is %d\n", TESTVAL);
    return 0;
}
```

Which doesn't compile and the error messages are:

```
error: operator "defined" requires an identifier
error: missing '(' in expression
```

One of the answers in the linked thread says the argument of `IMPLEMENT` is not known at compile-time, so we cannot use it with '#if defined'. But I don't think this is the case here. Can anyone explain why this doesn't compile?

Bonus question: is there any trick to safely replace the line `#if defined(x) && x`?

Comment: The accepted answer edited out a (IMO) nice trick. Maybe they didn't consider it as nice. Anyway, I write it here for future visitors: `#define IMPLEMENT(x,y) (defined(x##y) && (x))` and then use it as `#if IMPLEMENT(MY_MACRO,)`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Can anyone explain why this doesn't compile?

`IMPLEMENT(MY_MACRO)` is expanding `MY_MACRO` to `1` and then replacing it for `defined(1)`. `defined(1)` is invalid. `1` is not an identifier.

> is there any trick to replace the line #if defined(x) && x?

Yes, just use `#if x`. If it's not defined, then it's zero. Just `#if x`, no need for a defined.

```
#if MY_MACRO
```

Comment: you say `defined(1)` is invalid. But if we directly write `#if defined(MY_MACRO)` after the first line, it will compile. Although it is still technically `defined(1)`. This is where the confusion arises.

Comment: @polfosolఠ_ఠ `#if defined(MY_MACRO)` doesn't expand `MY_MACRO`. But `#if IMPLEMENT(MY_MACRO)` will expand `MY_MACRO`.

Comment: @polfosolఠ_ఠ, the arguments to a function-like macro are expanded before the macro itself is expanded.  The same does not apply to `defined`, which is an operator, not a macro (parentheses notwithstanding).